# R: How can I open a list of links to scrape the homepage of a news website?

Tags: r, web, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to build a web scraper to **scrape** articles published on [www.20min.ch](http://www.20min.ch), a news website, with R. Their api is openly accessible so I could create a dataframe containing titles, urls, descriptions, and timestamps with rvest. The next step would be to access every single link and create a list of article texts and combine it with my dataframe. However I don't know how to automatize the access to those articles. Ideally, I would like to read_html link 1, then copy the text with html node and then proceed to link 2...

This is what I wrote so far:

```
site20min <- read_xml("https://api.20min.ch/rss/view/1")

site20min

url_list <- site20min %>% html_nodes('link') %>% html_text()

df20min <- data.frame(Title = character(),
                      Zeit = character(),
                      Lead = character(),
                      Text = character()
                      )

 for(i in 1:length(url_list)){
      myLink <- url_list[i]
      site20min <- read_html(myLink)
            
      titel20min <- site20min %>% html_nodes('h1 span') %>% html_text()
      zeit20min <- site20min %>% html_nodes('#story_content .clearfix span') %>% html_text()
      lead20min <- site20min %>% html_nodes('#story_content h3') %>% html_text()
      text20min <- site20min %>% html_nodes('.story_text') %>% html_text()  
           
      df20min_a <- data.frame(Title = titel20min)
      df20min_b <- data.frame(Zeit = zeit20min)
      df20min_c <- data.frame(Lead = lead20min)
      df20min_d <- data.frame(Text = text20min)
              }
```

What I need is R to open every single link and extract some information:

```
site20min_1 <- read_html("https://www.20min.ch/schweiz/news/story/-Es-liegen-auch-Junge-auf-der-Intensivstation--14630453")

  titel20min_1 <- site20min_1 %>% html_nodes('h1 span') %>% html_text()
  zeit20min_1 <- site20min_1 %>% html_nodes('#story_content .clearfix span') %>% html_text()
  lead20min_1 <- site20min_1 %>% html_nodes('#story_content h3') %>% html_text()
  text20min_1 <- site20min_1 %>% html_nodes('.story_text') %>% html_text()
```

It should not be too much of a problem to rbind this to a dataframe. but at the moment some of my results turn out empty.

thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with setting up a dataframe. You can loop through each link and `rbind` it to your existing dataframe structure.

First, you can set a vector of urls to be looped through. Based on the edit, here is such a vector:

```
url_list <- c("http://www.20min.ch/ausland/news/story/14618481",
              "http://www.20min.ch/schweiz/news/story/18901454",
              "http://www.20min.ch/finance/news/story/21796077",
              "http://www.20min.ch/schweiz/news/story/25363072",
              "http://www.20min.ch/schweiz/news/story/19113494",
              "http://www.20min.ch/community/social_promo/story/20407354",
              "https://cp.20min.ch/de/stories/635-stressfrei-durch-den-verkehr-so-sieht-der-alltag-von-busfahrer-claudio-aus")
```

Next, you can set a dataframe structure that includes everything you're looking to gether.

```
# Set up the dataframe first
df20min <- data.frame(Title = character(),
                      Link = character(),
                      Lead = character(),
                      Zeit = character())
```

Finally, you can loop through each url in your list and add the relevant info to your dataframe.

```
# Go through a loop
for(i in 1:length(url_list)){
  myLink <- url_list[i]
  site20min <- read_xml(myLink)

  # Extract the info
  titel20min <- site20min %>% html_nodes('title') %>% html_text()
  link20min <- site20min %>% html_nodes('link') %>% html_text() 
  zeit20min <- site20min %>% html_nodes('pubDate') %>% html_text()
  lead20min <- site20min %>% html_nodes('description') %>% html_text()

  # Structure into dataframe
  df20min_a <- data.frame(Title = titel20min, Link =link20min, Lead = lead20min)
  df20min_b <- df20min_a [-(1:2),]
  df20min_c <- data.frame(Zeit = zeit20min)

  # Insert into final dataframe
  df20min <- rbind(df20min, cbind(df20min_b,df20min_c))
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I need to open a list of links, not modify one single link.

Comment: It will work for a list of links just as easily - you just have to modify it for that. Since your question didn't clarify, I assumed it was looping through links that were all similar. If you provide the list of links I can edit it so that it does what you need. Otherwise, you can try yourself. Instead of looping 1 through n, loop 1 through the number of links stored in some vector.

Comment: Updated. Your help is much obliged! Cheers from self-quarantine.

Comment: I added the addition. Let me know whether that works for you.

Comment: it's still not working but we're getting closer. I think it loops through the list now but the results are still empty. I'll update my code.